# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'save' - django python

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save image to ImageField

```
location = Location()
image = Image()
name = urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1]                            
image.bild.save(name, File(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), save=False))
image.von_location = location
image.save()
```

but I am getting

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'save'
```

why is this? what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `File` constructor doesn't take a `save` argument. Perhaps you mean to pass it to `image.bild.save()` instead.

Comment: so i will call ``image.bild.save()`` without ``save`` argument?

Comment: You're not passing `save` to it at all. Look harder.

Comment: oh holy sh** :D sorry, didnot see it